# How to get Firebase Remote Config value into firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-remote-config

I try to get a Remote Config value into a firebase function.

How can I achive this ?

------------------------ improved question after first hint from Doug ------------------------

There is a `admin.remoteConfig().getTemplate()` method available.

Below is a semi-working example.

In the code below, I see that defaultVal is of type RemoteConfigParameterValue?. But how do I convert it to a number in typescript ??

```
const remoteConfigTemplate = await admin.remoteConfig().getTemplate();

const defaultVal = remoteConfigTemplate.parameters["video_max_duration"].defaultValue

const videoMaxDurationDefaultValue: number = Number(defaultVal); // XXXXXX does not work XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Remote Config has an [API available through the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc).  You can also use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest).